# Oracle selection through php won't show on my page

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

### *I'm having some problem with accessing Oracle database records through PHP - OCI8 functions*

So I am trying to echo any record in PHP from my Oracle database to my page.

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('SYSTEM', '1234', 'localhost/orcl');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}else{
    echo "Successfully connected!"; 
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM userPage'; 
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1]; 
}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

I am not getting any error back so my connection is valid and also my query is working well on my table because if I change the name of the table in the query I am getting an error that my table does not exist.

I have almost tried everything from [oci8 functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.oci8.php) and all my result is a blank page.

In Oracle I have created the table correctly and trying to access the data through SYSTEM so I should't have privilige problems.

I am using Oracle 12c, instant client 12_2 windows 7 operating system (didn't work on win10 at all), XAMPP v3.2.4.

Any ideas would help a lot. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I do not see error. This is a similary code from the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.oci-fetch-array.php). Are you sure that you have at least one row in your table?

Comment: A common quick debugging solution to check (if you can't step through your code) is to add various `echo` statements (or `print_r()` for complex data types) to see what is happening and where it gets to.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, I was able to solve this problem. I am extremely beginner in Oracle-sqldeveloper and at first I only saved my database after the rows being inserted, I didn't know I had to commmit changes. Sorry for the question but I was desperate.